Beta Distribution and the Moment Problem (citation needed)
As I understand it, the Beta Distribution is uniquely defined in terms of its moments (i.e. the Moment Problem has a unique solution on the values of its moments). The Wikipedia article of the Beta Distribution even states as much, yet, the reference on Wikipedia (Billingsley, "Probability and Measure") only provides the uniqueness for arbitrary distributions with a positive radius of convergence of the moment generating function - a result I cannot find for the Beta Distribution in the literature.
If I were to derive the radius of convergence myself, I would upper-bound the coefficients of the moment generating function with (1/k!), whose k-th root converges to 0, and use the Cauchy-Hadamard-Theorem to obtain an infinite radius of convergence. But my understanding of the radius of convergence is rather superficial and I would rather not include a derivation in my text, which otherwise has absolutely nothing to do with that. As the result appears rather immediate, I find it hard to believe, that there is no published proof, although I cannot find one. Does anyone here know of a reference I could cite?

Not all immediate results have a published proof, since they are, in a sense, "obvious". And it is obvious that $1  +\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \prod_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac{\alpha+r}{\alpha+\beta+r} \right) \frac{t^k}{k!}$ converges by comparison with $1  +\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}=e^{-t}$.

The MGF for any bounded distribution will (obviously) be analytic, and this includes Beta distributions.  A good Calculus textbook that states a version of Taylor's Theorem with Remainder would be an adequate reference.

Seems, like I will have to include at least a sketch of a derivation in the text nonetheless, as these "obvious" arguments are likely not at all obvious for my audience. Thanks a lot, though.

It looks like you're on the right track.
Suppose a distribution is supported on a bounded interval $[a,b],$ such as $[a,b]=[0,1]$ for any Beta distribution.  Consequently it assigns no probability to any value of magnitude greater than $M = \max(|a|,|b|).$  If $X$ is a random variable with this distribution and $z = s + it$ is any Complex number,
$$|E[\exp(zX)]|  \le E[\exp(sX)\,|\exp(itX)|] = E[\exp(sX)] \le \exp(sM) \lt \infty,$$
permitting us to expand the left hand side as an absolutely convergent Taylor series
$$|E[\exp(zX)]| = \bigg|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} E[(zX)^n]\bigg| = \bigg|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \mu_n\bigg| \le \bigg|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^nM^n}{n!}\bigg| = |\exp(zM)|.$$
The case $t=0$ gives the moment generating function while the case $s=0$ gives the characteristic function.  This all shows how the moments determine both the mgf and the cf; that both exist; and--finally--since the cf determines the distribution, the point is proven.

Because the moment generating function is infinitely differentiable, it is an analytic function with a convergent Taylor series.  It is reasonably simple to derive this function from scratch.  To do this, we first observe that the moment generating function for the beta distribution (with shape parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$) is given by:
$$m(t) \equiv \mathbb{E}(\exp(tX)) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \int \limits_0^1 \exp(tx) x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \ dx.$$
To facilitate analysis, we will also define the generalised function:
$$m_k(t) \equiv \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+k) \Gamma(\beta)} \int \limits_0^1 \exp(tx) x^{\alpha+k-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \ dx,$$
and recognise that $m=m_0$.  (The function $m_k$ is the MGF for the case where we use shape parameters $\alpha+k$ and $\beta$).  The derivatives of the MGF for the beta distribution can be written as:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^k m}{dt^k}(t)
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \frac{d^k}{dt^k} \int \limits_0^1 \exp(tx) x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k} \exp(tx) x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \int \limits_0^1 \exp(tx) x^{\alpha+k-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+k)} \cdot m_k(t) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+k)} \cdot m_k(t) \\[6pt]
&= \bigg( \prod_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac{\alpha+r}{\alpha+\beta+r} \bigg) \cdot m_k(t). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Now, since $m_k(0) = \int_0^1 \text{Beta}(x|\alpha+k, \beta) \ dx = 1$ for all $k$ (since this is just an integral over the entire support of a density function) we then have:
$$\frac{d^k m}{dt^k}(0) = \prod_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac{\alpha+r}{\alpha+\beta+r}.$$
Consequently, the Maclaurin series for the moment generating function is:
$$\begin{align}
m(t) 
&= m(0) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{d^k m}{dt^k}(0) \frac{t^k}{k!} \\[6pt]
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \bigg( \prod_{r=0}^{k-1} \frac{\alpha+r}{\alpha+\beta+r} \bigg) \frac{t^k}{k!}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Since none of the preceeding steps limit the allowable values of $t$ there is no limit on the radius of convergence (i.e., this form is valid for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$).
